# Sorting List Data as per an Enum

Tags: java, sorting

I have a List of String `l=[mean,max,min,std,flag]`
I have another enum

```
public enum ListOrder{
    mean(0), 
    std(1), 
    max(2), 
    min(3), 
    flag(100);

    private int value;

    private ListOrder(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**My try :-**

```
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<ListOrder>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(ListOrder o1, ListOrder o2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
```

But this is not working as ListOrder is not the superClass of String. Can anyone please help me how can i do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the `List` contains `String` you need to provide a `Comparator<String>` which will look the `Enum` to sort :

   ```
   List<String> l = Arrays.asList("mean", "max", "min", "std", "flag");
   Collections.sort(l, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(ListOrder.valueOf(o1).getValue(), 
                                                   ListOrder.valueOf(o2).getValue()));
   ```

   [***Workable Demo***](https://ideone.com/MNV0v8)

---

2. If the `List` directly contains `ListOrder` you just need to tell to sort on value if the Enum elements are not provided in the order your need

   ```
   List<ListOrder> l = Arrays.asList(ListOrder.mean, ListOrder.max, ListOrder.min, ListOrder.std, ListOrder.flag);
   Collections.sort(l, Comparator.comparing(ListOrder::valueOf));
   ```

   [***Workable Demo***](https://ideone.com/PmliOd)

   If they are in the order you need, a simple `Collections.sort(l);` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Enums is already Comparable with simple `Collections.sort(l);`

```
ArrayList<ListOrder> l = new ArrayList<ListOrder>();

l.add(ListOrder.mean);
l.add(ListOrder.max);
l.add(ListOrder.min);
l.add(ListOrder.std);
l.add(ListOrder.flag);

Collections.sort(l);

System.out.println(l.toString());
```

Output :

```
[mean, std, max, min, flag]
```

Comment: Just to clarify that this sorting will be based on ordinals of the elements and not on their values. Simply, constantDeclaredFirst) < (constantDeclaredLater even if constantDeclaredFirst.getValue() > constantDeclaredLater.getValue()

Answer (score 0):

I could know what you wand.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("mean", "max", "min", "std", "flag");

    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return ListOrder.valueOf(o1).getValue() - ListOrder.valueOf(o2).getValue();
        }
    });
    for (String s : l) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```